Debian 12 - Automatically set Natural Scrolling on bluetooth keyboard//trackpad
I have a bluetooth keyboard/trackpad.  I've paired it nicely with my PC (integrated Bluetooth) and it works.  Except the trackpad is in "natural" mode.  I'm old school and want to make it work the way I'm used to.
I can fix this with
/usr/bin/xinput set-prop 'Bluetooth Keyboard Mouse' 'libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled' 1

And now it works just fine.
But, of course, the keyboard goes to sleep to save battery life and when it reconnects... and we're backwards again.
Looking at previous answers the udev rules mention idVendor and idProduct, but this isn't USB, it's bluetooth.
Looking at dmesg output I can see
[37649.499617] input: Bluetooth Keyboard Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:1915:0040.0014/input/input63

And udevadm info -ap /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:1915:0040.0014 gives
  looking at device '/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:1915:0040.0014':
    KERNEL=="0005:1915:0040.0014"
    SUBSYSTEM=="hid"
    DRIVER=="hid-generic"
    ATTR{country}=="00"
    ATTR{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/virtual/misc/uhid':
    KERNELS=="uhid"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="misc"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

Instead of looking at -ap I looked at -tp and this appears to be the relevant entry:
    └─input/input63
      ┆ P: /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:1915:0040.0014/input/input63
      ┆ M: input63
      ┆ R: 63
      ┆ U: input
      ┆ E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:1915:0040.0014/input/input63
      ┆ E: SUBSYSTEM=input
      ┆ E: PRODUCT=5/1915/40/1
      ┆ E: NAME="Bluetooth Keyboard Mouse"
      ┆ E: PHYS="e4:c7:67:ee:d5:0d"
      ┆ E: UNIQ="c1:4a:8c:47:2c:8a"
      ┆ E: PROP=0
      ┆ E: EV=17
      ┆ E: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
      ┆ E: REL=1943
      ┆ E: MSC=10
      ┆ E: MODALIAS=input:b0005v1915p0040e0001-e0,1,2,4,k110,111,112,113,114,r0>
      ┆ E: USEC_INITIALIZED=37652275214
      ┆ E: ID_INPUT=1
      ┆ E: ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
      ┆ E: ID_BUS=bluetooth
      ┆ E: TAGS=:seat:
      ┆ E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:

My first attempt was
KERNEL=="input", ACTION=="add", ENV{NAME}="Bluetooth Keyboard Mouse", RUN+="/home/sweh/bin/fixtrackpad"

But this fails to trigger.
So I'm not sure what rules I need for udev so I can trigger this!
